# PL/SQL Function Body Returning Error Text in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have two filed Price and Cost 
If Price < Cost I should get an error saying 
Item Price Should be Greater Item Than Cost
I need to created Validation In Oracle Apex

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation/tutorials for creating validations? What have you tried?

Comment: I know how to create validation. I am asking how to implement this or write this code.

Answer (score 3):

That would be a validation of a "PL/SQL function which returns error text" type.

```
if :P1_PRICE < :P1_COST then
   return 'Item price should be greater than cost';
end if;
return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two item as like :P0_PRICE and :P0_COST
After that you Create a validation of type "Function Body returning Boolean" with source code

```
BEGIN
 IF :P0_PRICE < :P0_COST THEN
   RETURN true;
 END IF;
  RETURN false;
END;
```